# .Call: REAL() loses dimensions of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Inside a function of type `SEXP myfun(SEXP n, SEXP d)` I allocate an (n, d)-matrix which contains the result of a function computed in C:

```
SEXP res = PROTECT(allocMatrix(REALSXP, n, d));
```

I would like to 'fill' this matrix (it can then be returned by `myfun`) and thus would like to convert it to an (n, d)-matrix in C (or pointer or so). How can this be done?

If `res` was a vector, I could do:

```
double *res_ = REAL(res);
```

and then walk through `res_` with a for loop. However, when I use that for the above matrix, it loses its dimension, i.e., indexing via `res_[i][j]` for computing the result fails. Of course one could work with a vector and keep track of the row/col indices oneself, but ideally I would like to simply write `res_[i][j]`. Is this doable without significant amount of extra code?

Comment: You'll probably find life easier if you use RCpp...

Comment: Hi Hadley, indeed, but it's for a package and we don't want to depend on Rcpp just for that.... Also, it is unclear to me how much this 'overhead' affects run time. After all, we want to go to C to make things very fast... Cheers from Waterloo, Marius (PS: heard you've recently been to Toronto, hope you had a great time :-) )

Comment: Marius, the Rcpp package has pretty extensive benchmarking examples that show that there is no overhead.  I'd love for you to prove me wrong.  Cheers from Chicago.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks a lot! Cheers to Chicago!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix is going to be stored as a vector internally, which should imply that `[i][j]` is meaningless in C.  Here is an example from **[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Attributes)** on how you would do this:

```
    #include <R.h>
    #include <Rinternals.h>

    SEXP out(SEXP x, SEXP y)
    {
        R_len_t i, j, nx = length(x), ny = length(y);
        double tmp, *rx = REAL(x), *ry = REAL(y), *rans;
        SEXP ans;

        PROTECT(ans = allocMatrix(REALSXP, nx, ny));
        rans = REAL(ans);
        for(i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
            tmp = rx[i];
            for(j = 0; j < ny; j++)
                rans[i + nx*j] = tmp * ry[j];
        }
        UNPROTECT(1);
        return(ans);
    }
```

Comment: ... that was my fear, no more intuitive indexing available. Thanks. Another option is to allocate a double-indexed vector (= matrix) and then copy the elements there. But that's inefficient of course.

Answer (score 4):

Speed if course very important, but I also like code clarity.  The solution by BrodieG could be written as a *much* shorter RcppArmadillo function -- it really is just a single outer product:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]     

// [[Rcpp::export]]         
arma::mat outCpp(arma::colvec x, arma::rowvec y) {
    return x * y;
}
```

If we test this against Brodie's (renamed to `outC()`) we get his:

```
 R> sourceCpp("/tmp/marius.cpp")         
 R> library(rbenchmark)
 R> a <- as.numeric(1:3)
 R> b <- as.numeric(1:4)
 R> outC(a, b)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    2    4    6    8
 [3,]    3    6    9   12
 R> outCpp(a, b)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    2    4    6    8
 [3,]    3    6    9   12

 R> benchmark(outC(a,b), outCpp(a,b), replications=1e5)[,1:4]
           test replications elapsed relative
 1   outC(a, b)       100000   0.382    1.000
 2 outCpp(a, b)       100000   0.484    1.267
 R>
```

So running 100,000 replications takes 380 vs 480 msec.

That means for each call, the difference is one millionth of a second.  I think I take for having a single line of code that is easier to read and maintain.